# How to get odd occurring text in a String in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string

I have a String and I want to get another string out of it which has only characters at odd occuring positions.

For example if i have a string called ABCDEFGH, the output I expect is ACEG since the character indexes are at 0,2,4,6 respectively. I did it using a loop, but there should be one line implementation in Ruby (perhaps using Regex?).

Comment: I must say that looks an awful lot like a homework question :P Anyway, I don't know anough Ruby to help you, but shouldn't you post how far you got instead of just asking for a function like that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. You're trying to get the indexes in one string of the characters in another? Is that what this function should return?

Comment: @Jasper : aw.. its a simple implementation (which i've already done, but it looks very long). I am very sure Ruby folks surely have one line implementations..

Comment: @Chuck : yes it should return that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one-line solution:

```
"BLAHBLAH".split('').enum_for(:each_with_index).find_all { |c, i| i % 2 == 0 }.collect(&:first).join
```

Or:

```
''.tap do |res|
  'BLAHBLAH'.split('').each_with_index do |char, index|
    res << c if i % 2 == 0
  end
end
```

One more variant:

```
"BLAHBLAH".split('').enum_slice(2).collect(&:first).join
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>> "ABCDEFGH".gsub /(.)./,'\1'
=> "ACEG"
```

Comment: looks like a simple gsub is the best in the end

Comment: how to get even indexed characters?

Answer (score 2):

Some other ways:

Using [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html) methods

```
"BLAHBLAHBLAH".each_char.each_slice(2).map(&:first).join
```

Using [regular expressions](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000812):

```
"BLAHBLAHBLAH".scan(/(.).?/).join
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the run-time speed but it's one line of processing.

```
res =  ""; 
"BLAHBLAH".scan(/(.)(.)/) {|a,b| res += a}
res # "BABA"
```

Comment: Why not just `"BLAHBLAH".scan(/(.)./).map(&:first).join`? Don't need an accumulator or two captures

Answer (score 1):

```
(0..string.length).each_with_index { |x,i| puts string[x] if i%2 != 0 }
```

Comment: Careful. Ruby1.9 Strings are not enumerable